# SignalR 2.0 Tutorial Does not Work VS2017 Community

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to test the following tutorial from Microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

I followed every steps but it did not work. I am using VS 2017 Community and .NET 4.6.1. JQuery 3.3.1 and SignalR 2.2.2

The page starts but it does not ask me to enter a name. It stops here:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
```

Also, no signalr/hubs is created.

Any idea?

Comment: I added map.SignalR(); to Owin file and it fixed

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the referenced scripts in "index.html" are correct. These filenames should match with the .js files in your "Script" directory inside your project.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

I had to change the version of **jquery** from `3.1.1` to `3.3.1` and the version of **jquery.signalR** from `2.2.1` to `2.2.2`.

If all references are correct check if you correctly mapped signalR inside your `Startup.cs`. The code should look something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Maps SignalR hubs to the app builder pipeline at "/signalr".
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```